# Python - Using accented letters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, non-ascii-characters

I'm having an issue with **accented letters** in Python. It can't really replace accented letters with non-accented letters because it won't recognize the words when searching for them in the dataframe.

The code below adds to new columns to the dataframe '**df_sb**' and combines a string (Section Début or Section da Tête) with the content of another column.

The thing is, when I run the block below in my main script file, it will correctly write and display the words with accented letters (*Section Début* and *Section da Tête*). However, this needs to be executed in a different file by calling a function. When I call the function and it returns me the df_sb dataframe (with the two columns), it messes up the accented letters for some reason. I don't understand why this is happening.

**BLOCK 1**:

```
from ipynb.fs.full.Untitled1 import *
df_sb = func_1()
```

**BLOCK 2:**

```
def func_1():
    import pandas as pd
    df_sb = ['One' , 'Two', 'Three']
    df_sb = pd.DataFrame(df_sb)
    df_sb.columns = ['NAME']


    for i in range(0,len(df_sb['NAME']),1):
        df_sb['SECTION_DEBUT'] = "Section Début: " + df_sb.loc[:,'NAME'] + " "
        df_sb['SECTION_TETE'] = "Section da Tête: " + df_sb.loc[:,'NAME'] + " "
    return(df_sb)
```

-> Output when calling and running function on the same file:

[image]

-> Output when calling and running function on a **different file**:
[image]

How should deal with this?

Comment: Check for the encoding of character by the editor

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Hello @snakecharmerb, I just edited my comment. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

### This is a source code encoding issue

When you get the correct output, your editor and the Python interpreter the code is being run in both agree on the source encoding, and so you get the non-ASCII characters represented correctly.

When you run it the second time, the interpreter is not using the same encoding as the editor. From the specific mojibake produced, it looks like the editor used UTF-8 while the interpreter is using latin-1. Alas, that's the wrong choice!

Fortunately, there's an easy way to tell the Python interpreter what the correct encoding of your file is. At the very top of the file, above any other code (but optionally below the "shebang" line, e.g. `#!/user/bin/python`) put something like this:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

There are in fact quite a wide variety of variant forms you could write that in (several of which might be recognized by some IDEs or other sophisticated text editors to make sure *they* are also using the specified encoding). The full details of this kind of encoding declaration are spelled out in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: Hi @Blckknght. I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it keeps presenting the characters incorrectly. I've added the line as first line on my comment, but that seem to make a difference.